# How do I read from a json-lines file into a Dataset with an immutable.HashMap?

Tags: json, scala, hashmap, apache-spark-dataset, jsonlines

I have the following classes,

```
case class myClass (a: String, b: Boolean, c: Double, d: HashMap[String, E])
case class E (f: String, g: Int)
```

the following code to load into this from a json file into a `Dataset[myClass]`,

```
mySparkSession.read.schema(Encoders.product[myClass].schema).json("myData.json").as[myClass]
```

and a .json(-lines) file with lines like this:

```
{"a": "text","b": "false","c": 123456.78,"d": ["text", [{"f": "text"},{"g": 1}]]}
```

I get the following error while running the code:

> failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException:
>   File 'generated.java', Line 331, Column 75: No applicable
>   constructor/method found for actual parameters "java.lang.String,
>   boolean, double, scala.collection.immutable.Map"; candidates are:
>   "my.package.name.objname$myClass(java.lang.String, boolean, double,
>   scala.collection.immutable.HashMap)"

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can try with import collection.mutable.Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
case class myClass (a: String, b: Boolean, c: Double, d: Map[String, E])
```

I've found that using `df.as[myClass]` can be a bit picky about which type of `Map` you use. Without the `import` it defaults to `scala.collection.Map`, and that will fail as well.

Comment: A similar solution was used, basically the same with a conversion as construction overloading: ```def this(a: String, b: Boolean, c: Double, d: Map[String, E]) {
            this(a, b, c, (HashMap[String, E]()++d).asInstanceOf[HashMap[String, E]])
        }```